# Match a whole string variable using python regex

Tags: python

I am new to python.

I want to write a regex to find a whole string using re.match.

For example,

```
word1=I 
word2=U
str_to_match = word1+"[There could be some space in between]"+  word2[this is the end of string I want to match]"
```

In this case, it should match `I[0 or more spaces in between]U`.
It shouldn't match `abI[0 or more spaces in between]U`, OR `abI[0 or more spaces in between]Ucd`, OR
`I[0 or more spaces in between]Ucd`.

I know you could use boundary `\b` to set the word boundary but since there could be a number of spaces in between word1 and word2, the whole string is like a variable, not a fixed string, it won't work for me:

```
ret=re.match(r"\b"+word1+r"\s+" +word2+r"\b")
```

not working

Does anyone know how could I find the correct way to match this case?
Thanks!

Comment: do you mean `\s*`?

Comment: and are you really trying to use match?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[match only matches at the beginning of the string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match).  Which since you are using \b should not be what you want.  `findall` will find all matching strings.
If you want to find the first occurrence and just test if it exists in the string, and not find all matches you can use `search`:

```
word1 = 'I'
word2 = 'U'
ret = re.findall(rf"\b{word1}\s*{word2}\b"," I   U  IU  I  U  aI U I Ub")
print(ret)
ret = re.search(rf"\b{word1}\s*{word2}\b"," IUb  .I    U ")
print(ret)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This is really helpful. I have a small question, what is the "f" here in the brace (rf"\b{word1}\s*{word2}\b ...?

Comment: Hi, that is a formatted string literal using the `f` prefix. 
 https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals  It evaluates the expression inside the brackets and inserts it into the string